# Does my advisor dislike me?

Tags: advisor

I am a phd student in a lab. PI has been sending out an email to everyone to prepare for a conference. They already booked hotels and flights and all. I only noticed this because the other phd student in the lab told me about it. So I was a little shocked about the news. I have assumed I will also be there. I am very shy at asking these kinds of things, but of course, I know I should have been more vocal about this.

Does he think it was not worth asking me? He knew I wanted to go (or at least I thought he knew). Does he simply dislike me? Should I tell him what I think?

Comment: Why do you think this is not just a simple mistake?  Don't you ever text the wrong person?

Comment: Very smart people easily make mistakes all the time. I don't understand what you mean by "very lengthy accomodations for everyone", it sounds like you were just left off an email. Is there something besides that?

Comment: Agree with the others. Beyond that, most of the questions here (does he dislike me? why didn't he ask me?) can only be answered by your advisor.

Comment: "or at least I thought he knew". Most of our assumptions, in social life as well in science, are **wrong**.

Comment: Did you submit a contribution to the conference? Did your PhD colleagues subimt a contribution? are you the same seniority as the other PhDs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best guess, mine and that of several commenters, is just that you were inadvertently left off of some email list. Even a typo in an email address would do it if it isn't well maintained. Or you might find something in your junk/spam folder.

If it were intentional, then I doubt that you would have any doubt about it and you'd have seen many other signs.

Just send a note, or visit the office, and say you seem to be not getting emails sent to others. It will probably be cleared up. If you get a good response then you can follow up with something about the conference or any other concern you have.

No, don't tell him how you feel, unless  you get a negative message in a face to face talk. The issue might even have been caused by a clerical staff member and the faculty member could be unaware.

But being to "shy" to speak up isn't going to get you anywhere, now or in the future. Speak when you have a need. That was a hard lesson for me, actually, and it cost me a lot until I learned a better way.

Comment: Email can go missing for more reasons than listed here.  Just because it is not in the inbox or in the spam folder does not mean it was not sent.  I've learned this the hard way.

Comment: +1 especially for the last paragraph. Being able to talk with your PI is crucial to getting through the PhD. Like Buffy, I had difficulty with this and I might have finished eighteen months earlier (and a lot happier!) if I'd been more confident in talking to my supervisor when I ran into difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes he dislikes you and he intentionally left you out of the group going to a conference.
In fact, he is secretly preparing your dismissal letter.

Can you believe this?

I don't. Now that you see in writing the most perverse trick your anxiety is playing on you, do you see how absurd it is?

Even if he dislikes you, you have been hired to contribute to the group work, not everyone can be friend of everyone, but people can still work together (I would even say that it is best to have friends outside the close colleagues).

Plain tell (or write) the PI that you would like to join the conference, but you did not receive the invitation to book the flight/hotel, so you are wondering if you should contact the secretary or if you should do it on your own. And wait for his response.